# How to create PSQL stored functions via flamerobin

Tags: firebird, flamerobin

I have installed flamerobin admin tool 0.9.2 with Firebird 3. Is there any straightforward way to create [PSQL stored functions](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-funcs.html) via flamerobin and how? That would help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating stored functions works the same as creating stored procedures. For FlameRobin (like ISQL) that means switch statement terminators of FlameRobin using `set term` and provide the DDL of the function:

```sql
set term #;
create function f(x integer) returns integer
as
begin
  return x + 1;
end#
set term ;#
```

That said, development of FlameRobin has ground to a halt, and it was never updated to support Firebird 3. So, although you can execute DDL like this, you might miss certain code completion and metadata support for features introduced in Firebird 3. You may want to consider switching to another tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! That saved me from a lot of trouble. Flamerobin is a very good tool and at the same time free whatever that means. Regards